# Bars do not disappear watching videos full screen

Tags: 12.04, video, gnome-classic, fullscreen, panel

I just installed Ubuntu 12.04. I switched to the classic view because I didn't feel comfortable with the unity.

When I watch videos or movies, I double-click (as always) to make them full screen. But then, the bars (I don't know if this is correct wording. I mean the bar on the top which has "Applications" and "Places", and the bar on the bottom with the windows.) do not disappear. They remain above the video and block part of the content (especially the below part with the subtitles :) ).

What should I do?

PS: I guess this is a very simple thing and I'm a little ashamed for not knowing the solution.

Answer (score 1):

Double clicking on the title bar maximizes the window.  That is not the same as full screen mode.  To enter full screen mode you need to click on the button that says full screen mode, or right click in the display area and choose the full screen option from the menu.

Comment: Most video players use the F key for full screen, or F11 if this doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a direct solution to your problem but merely a notice and a secondary solution to your problem: From what you've described you're using GNOME 3, which isn't really a "classic gnome," as you've described it.

If you install the `gnome` package using:

`sudo apt-get install gnome`

Then you can select the real Gnome Classic from the login screen, which won't cause the problem you're having.